# Mongoose document: Execute hook manually for testing

Tags: node.js, testing, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'd like to test some document transformation which is executed in a Mongoose `pre` `save` hook. Simplified example:

```
mySchema.pre('save', function(callback) {
  this.property = this.property + '_modified';
  callback();
});
```

Test:

```
var testDoc = new MyDocument({ property: 'foo' });
// TODO -- how to execute the hook?
expect(testDoc.property).to.eql('foo_modified');
```

How can I manually execute this hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here’s what we did at the end. We replaced the `$__save` function with a no operation implementation:

```
// overwrite the $__save with a no op. function, 
// so that mongoose does not try to write to the database
testDoc.$__save = function(options, callback) {
  callback(null, this);
};
```

This prevents hitting the database, but the `pre` hook obviously still gets called.

```
testDoc.save(function(err, doc) {
  expect(doc.property).to.eql('foo_modified');
  done();
});
```

Mission accomplished.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for Mongoose v5.9 in 2020 unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

As of Mongoose 5.9, using the `$__save` override doesn't seem to work, so here is a replacement that doesn't require you to call the `save()` method directly:

```
const runPreSaveHooks = async (doc) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    doc.constructor._middleware.execPre("save", doc, [doc], (error) => {
      error ? reject(error) : resolve(doc);
    });
  });
};

await runPreSaveHooks(testDoc);
expect(testDoc.property).to.eql('foo_modified');
```